# How to delete only orphan child rows with ON DELETE?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design

I have a parent table and a child table. A parent row stores the foreign key to the child row. If I set the constraint on the foreign key to ON DELETE CASCADE then that will throw an error when I want to delete a parent row where the foreign key points to a child row that is in use by additional parent rows.

This SQL query lists the child rows and how many times they occur. Parent row is the person and the child row is the country.

`SELECT country_id, country, COUNT(person.id) FROM nobel_prizes.person JOIN nobel_prizes.countries c on c.id = person.country_id GROUP BY country_id;`

Using the results from this, I could delete orphaned rows easily. But is there a more proper method to do this?

Comment: *A parent row stores the foreign key to the child row.* In commonly used terms your situation is backward. As a rule a parent have a lot of childs. In your particular situation you cannot remove "childs" w/o external references on it with FK action. Use event procedure or AFTER DELETE trigger instead.

Comment: Please publish the table definitions as text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple of concepts reversed.

It is customary that the table with the foreign key is called the child. The table referenced by the foreign key is called the parent. In your case, the `person` table is a child of the `countries` table, not the other way around.

If you define the foreign key in `person` with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, then deleting a parent row from `countries` results in deleting all child rows in `person` that reference the deleted row to also be deleted.

An orphan row is one that has no parent. It's a violation of referential integrity.

There is no reverse cascading operation supported by declarative referential integrity (aka foreign keys). That is, if you delete the last row in `person` for a given country, it does not delete that country. It is not a violation of referential integrity for a row in `countries` to have zero child rows in `person` depend on it. That's not an orphan, it's just a parent with no children (yet).

If you want to manually find countries that have zero persons referencing it, use a query like this:

```
SELECT c.country_id, c.country, COUNT(p.id) 
FROM nobel_prizes.countries c
LEFT OUTER JOIN nobel_prizes.person p on c.id = p.country_id 
GROUP BY c.country_id
HAVING COUNT(p.id) = 0;
```

You need to use outer join in this case, because an inner join would match only those rows in `countries` that have one or more matching rows in `person`. To find childless countries, you specifically want those with zero child rows in `person`.

I would not expect there to be a need to delete rows from `countries`. There are currently only 195 countries on Earth.

Comment: Yes, thanks for caching that. I have edited to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution which uses AFTER DELETE trigger:

```
-- tables
CREATE TABLE child (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY 
);
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  child_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES child (id)
);
```

```
-- trigger which deletes orphan childs
CREATE TRIGGER tr
AFTER DELETE ON parent
FOR EACH ROW 
DELETE FROM child
WHERE child.id = OLD.child_id -- test a child of deleted parent row
  AND NOT EXISTS (            -- check that there is no another references
    SELECT NULL
    FROM parent
    WHERE OLD.child_id = parent.child_id
    );
```

```
-- sample data
INSERT INTO child VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO parent VALUES (11,1), (12,1), (21,2), (31,3), (32,3);
SELECT * FROM parent;
SELECT * FROM child;
```

| id | child_id |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 |
| 21 | 2 |
| 31 | 3 |
| 32 | 3 |

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

```
-- delete a row. According child is not deleted because another reference exists.
DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = 11;
SELECT * FROM parent;
SELECT * FROM child;
```

| id | child_id |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 |
| 21 | 2 |
| 31 | 3 |
| 32 | 3 |

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

```
-- delete a row. A child become orphan one, and it is deleted too
DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = 21;
SELECT * FROM parent;
SELECT * FROM child;
```

| id | child_id |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 |
| 31 | 3 |
| 32 | 3 |

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |

```
DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = 12;
SELECT * FROM parent;
SELECT * FROM child;
```

| id | child_id |
| --- | --- |
| 31 | 3 |
| 32 | 3 |

| id |
| --- |
| 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oPCzvJUA)